# Filter between two dates MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

I have a form where i created two text boxes to choose the start and end date and a button to filter the table in the form by the dates chosen.

My vba code does not work. Can someone help?

This is the code:

```
Private Sub Command150_Click()
If IsNull(Me.Text153) And IsNull(Me.Text155) Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
Else
    Me.Filter = "[Datum] BETWEEN #" & Me.Text153 & "# AND #" & Me.Text155 & "#"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End If
 
End Sub
```

Note: Text153 is start date, Text 155 is end date, Datum is the field in the table which is filtered.
The dates filtered should be >= Start date and <= End date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Datum* sounds German, so you may have to force a slash as the date separator:

```vb
Private Sub Command150_Click()

    Dim Filter  As String

    If IsNull(Me.Text153) Or IsNull(Me.Text155) Then
        Me.FilterOn = False
    Else
        Filter = "[Datum] BETWEEN #" & Format(Me.Text153, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND #" & Format(Me.Text155, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        ' Print the filter string to the Immediate window (press Ctrl+G).
        Debug.Print Filter
        Me.Filter = Filter
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If
 
End Sub
```